# git cloning fails with libcurl was built with SSL disabled

Tags: git, ssl, tortoisegit

git.exe clone   -v  "https://github.com/tdegrunt/mongodb-rest.git" "C:\mongodb-rest"

Initialized empty Git repository in C:/mongodb-rest/.git/
fatal: https://github.com/tdegrunt/mongodb-rest.git/info/refs download error - libcurl was built with SSL disabled, https: not supported!

I am using git clone via TortoiseGit and it fails for me with the above error.

Answer (score 2):

Try [msysgit](http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/), it is compiled with SSL supports.